# How to get a clear Fourier plane image using convex optical lens?

Tags: optics

I am trying to get a view of the Fourier optics plane using home apparatus as follows:

[image]

[image]

I am able to get the inverted image easily by adjusting the distances just right, but I am never able to get a clear image of the Fourier plane:

[image]

All I get is a "cloudy blob" with no distinguishable shape as I move a paper between the image plane and the convex lens.

Does anyone tried and succeeded, or know why this does not work?

Comment: https://youtu.be/wcRB3TWIAXE?t=273

Comment: @Rob thank you. i have watched those demos using proper monochromatic laser source, beam collimator & transparent letter cutouts... i'm not sure why my setup does not work using light source from a watch and a convex lens. If the clear inverted image can be formed, why can't a clear fourier plane image be formed as well?